# DJANGO: Create User in 'core' app when Contact created in 'other' app using Signals

Tags: django, django-users, django-signals

I want to create a User in a separate app called 'core' when a Contact is created in an app called 'bookings'.
I'm having trouble configuring the signal to handle this.

Currently, using the signal I'm checking if the User exists and either assigning the existing User to the Contact instance OR creating a new User and assigning.

I've tried setting the user attribute to allow null, and blank, etc. I keep getting the below warning:

> IntegrityError at /bookings/contacts/
> null value in column "user_id" of relation "bookings_contact" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (18, tesing@testing.com, 5555555, null).

bookings.models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True)
```

core.models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

"""
Creating a User in Core app to decuple the core app from the bookings app.
Email UNIQUE constraint handled in serializers.py and admin.py
"""

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

core.signals.handlers.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

from bookings.models import Contact
from core.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact)
def create_user_for_new_contact(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        email = instance.email
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            password = get_random_string(length=12)
            user = User.objects.create(email=email, password=password)
        instance.user = user
        instance.save()
```

core.apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        import core.signals.handlers
```

Comment: There is no need to create a signal. You can put `create query` for `user` table just after creating your `contact`.

Comment: Thanks @HemalPatel.
Where would that logic go and what would it look like?

Comment: lets say you have `name` value and with that value you're creating `contact` with Form or maybe direct query like this `contact.objects.create(name=name)` after that you can create user with that `name` and other fields whichever you're using for those tables. like `User.objects.create(first_name=first_name,....)`  Share your contact creation logic.

Comment: Got it.
The problem I'm having is that adding first_name and last_name to my Contact model doesn't end up turning into a migration file. Django isn't picking that up. Is there something funky going on in the Contact model because I have a User model associated as an attribute, which itself has first_name and last_name?

Comment: please share what you tried and your Errors if any. in post

Comment: @HemalPatel posted as an answer for a cleaner look.

Answer (score 0):

Contact model in bookings.models.py:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('bookings', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='contact',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

The terminal message when running 'makemigrations':
←[1mbookings\migrations\0002_alter_contact_email.py←[0m
- Alter field email on contact

User model in core.models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

"""
Creating a User in Core app to decuple the core app from the bookings app.
Email UNIQUE constraint handled in serializers.py and admin.py
"""

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

It doesn't seem to pick up the first_name and last_name?

Comment: At the Contacts endpoint could I pass through first_name and last_name to the User model instead of storing it on the Contact model?

Comment: because you used Custom User Model and you have only `email` field. as you can see in your Model. just create `User` with that same email you used to create `Contact`. 
you can also use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` instead custom User model. which will have first_name , last_name. email, password and few others. take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/)

Comment: Ok. So it seems I over complicated haha. Thanks @HemalPatel